# What steps are necessary to install Munin on RHEL to track performance of multiple servers

Tags: monitoring, munin

I need to keep track of network, CPU and memory utilization of an application that sits on 5 machines (apache, mysql, memcached). I thought I'd install Munin for this. But I'm getting a little lost in the documentation. Is there a simple step by step guide to setting up a multi-machine setup?

Comment: Is Munin available from the package manager? If so, that might take care of a lot of it for you...

Comment: I had to compile from source to make it work ! To me for ever... That's why I use Debian =)

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to be reasonably easy to follow:
 http://www.unix-tutorials.com/go.php?id=3617

If monitoring everything via SNMP w/ 5min updates is an acceptable option, Cacti might also be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running debian it's quite easy.

monitoring server: apt-get install munin munin-node

monitored servers: apt-get install munin-node

Munin is a really good monitoring tool and it has lot of good plugins. 
It's less "sexy" than Cacti but easier to configure.
And You can activate them on the note by simply symlinking /usr/shars/munin/plugins/ /etc/munin/plugins/ and editing /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node

Example for the apache plugin:

- cd /etc/munin/plugins
- ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/apache* .
- edit /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node and add:

  [apache_*]

  user root

note: you must enable the apache status module for this to work.

to check:

run: /etc/munin/plugins/apache_accesses

Comment: arg sorry, you are running RHEL !

Answer (score 0):

Munin is available from the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repositories.

Follow the instructions how to add the repository, then do

```
yum install munin-node
```

on all servers you want to monitor. Adjust /etc/munin/munin-node.conf to allow connections from your munin master.

On the monitoring node, do

```
yum install munin munin-node
```

Follow the [instructions](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/munin.conf) on the Munin wiki for how to configure Munin.